# Success and failure message with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing test script with Selenium WebDrvier. I have a problem with success/failure messages. Here's part of the code where i shout get the message. I don't know where I made a mistake so I would appreciate if someone could help me with it.

```
WebElement msg=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/p"));
            String text=msg.getText();
            Object expectedText;
            Asserts.assertEquals(text,expectedText);
```

Comment: Object expectedText; no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebElement msg=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/p"));
// Get the text value of an element
String actualTxt = msg.getText();
// Expected [instead of Object expectedText ==> String expected]
String expecteTxt = "";
// Assertion (String, String)
Asserts.assertEquals(actualTxt,expectedTxt);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *Assert* two *String* values try to *Assert* through :

```
void org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(String actual, String expected)
```

- Defination :

  ```
  void org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(String actual, String expected)
  Asserts that two Strings are equal. If they are not, an AssertionError is thrown.

  Parameters:
  actual the actual value
  expected the expected value
  ```
- Your code will be :

  ```
  import org.testng.Assert;

  WebElement msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/p"));
  String text = msg.getText();
  Asserts.assertEquals(text,expectedText);
  ```